# Ubuntu 18.04 updates blocked by Nvidia 340 driver problems "trying to overwrite file which is also in package"

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, 18.04, dpkg

My problem is caused by a registered bug in the Nvidia 340 drivers which installs clashing libraries, that's all known but the result is as below. Sadly, the root cause is now lost in the noise as I failed to notice the problem developing and tried to fix it!

Any attempt at update or fixing brings up something like below:

```
(Reading database ... 295094 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgles1_1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgles1:i386 (1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgles1_1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM.so.1', which is also in package nvidia-340 340.106-0ubuntu3
Preparing to unpack .../libglvnd-dev_1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libglvnd-dev:i386 (1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2) ...

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libglvnd-dev_1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM.so', which is also in package nvidia-340 340.106-0ubuntu3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgles1_1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libglvnd-dev_1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2_i386.deb
```

**How do I break this bottleneck and get my system updating again?**

I have tried:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Can I safely remove the something to free up the process? The packages below or the archives above, for instance, which seem to be causing the immediate problem. If I can remove them how do I do it?

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.

 libegl1-mesa-dev : Depends: libglvnd-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-dev : Depends: libglvnd-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libgles2-mesa-dev : Depends: libglvnd-dev but it is not going to be installed
```

I have found other answers that force the overwriting of the troublesome libraries but they are fraught with potential troubles and do not directly address the root of the problem, the released update fixes the problem not the symptoms and the answer below fulfils that update.

Answer (score 1):

So I went back to the bug and read the later comments and eventually found someone who seemed to know what he was doing but was installing the proposed release candidate. I followed his/her lead and did the same but left off the candidate bit and lo it worked. Here it is:

```
sudo apt download nvidia-340
sudo dpkg -i nvidia-340_340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_i386.deb
```

(You can type to `nvidia-340_340` then hit <kbd>tab</kbd> to complete)

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

The last bit is just common sense but for completeness. If you are following this don't type the full file name as it may have been updated. My machine is now back to normal thank you.